# why the date format is not giving correct value?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs, angular-moment

I am checking whether  the date format is valid of not .why this format is valid ?

```
  alert(moment('16-jun-199', 'DD-MMM-YYYY').isValid())
```

Why it is giving me true .It should be false .why ?
here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZH2kjC9QWwbdLwmvH2Tp?p=preview
where i am doing wrong .formate should be 'DD-MMM-YYYY'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
moment('16-jun-199', 'DD-MMM-YYYY',true).isValid())
```

Note: additional true flag for `strict` parsing. which tells moment to not to use wildcards and use exact match.

> Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to
>   undesired/unexpected behavior.
>
> For example, the following behavior can be observed:

```
 moment('2016 is a date', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid() //true, 2016 was
 matched
```

> As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument
>   to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the
>   format and input match exactly, including delimeters.

```
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD').isValid();       // true
moment('It is 2012-05-25', 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // false
moment('2012-05-25',       'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // true
moment('2012.05.25',       'YYYY-MM-DD', true).isValid(); // false
```

Source:https://momentjs.com/docs/